# Constructing an independent sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, does there exist a random variable $Z$ which is independent of $X$ but not $Y$? In other words, given two sigma algebras $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$, does there exist a sigma algebra which is independent of one and not the other?

I wanted to use this in this context. 
Let $$X_1 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{on } \mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1] \\ 0 & \text{on } \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \end{cases}$$ and $$X_2 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{on }[0,\tfrac{1}{2}] \\ -1 & \text{on } (\tfrac{1}{2}, 1]. \end{cases}$$ I wanted to know whether there exists a random variable independent of $X_2 - X_1$ but not $X_2$ or does there exist a sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$, which is independent of $\sigma(X_2 - X_1)$ but not $\sigma(X_2)$.

This might help.

$$X_2 - X_1 = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{on } \mathbb{Q}^{c} \cap [0,\tfrac{1}{2}] \\ 1 & \text{on } \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,\tfrac{1}{2}] \\ 0 & \text{on } \mathbb{Q}^{c} \cap (\tfrac{1}{2}, 1] \\ -1 & \text{on } \mathbb{Q} \cap (\tfrac{1}{2}, 1]. \end{cases}$$.

Therefore, $$\sigma(X_2 - X_1) =\{\emptyset, \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,\tfrac{1}{2}], \mathbb{Q}^{c} \cap [0,\tfrac{1}{2}],\mathbb{Q} \cap (\tfrac{1}{2},1],\mathbb{Q}^{c} \cap (\tfrac{1}{2},1],[0,1]\}. $$
$$\sigma(X_2) = \{\emptyset, [0,\tfrac{1}{2}],(\tfrac{1}{2},1],[0,1]\}$$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this on the n same sample space. For example if $\Omega=\{1,2\}$, $P(\{1\})=P(\{2\})=\frac 1  2$ and $X(1)=1, X(2)=2$, $Y(1)=2,Y(2)=1$ then the only random variables independent of $X$ are the constants $1$ and $2$. So $Z$  must be  a constant, hence independent of $Y$ also.

Comment: $X$ is not  a constant  (because $X(1) \neq X(2)$) and $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. (In fact $Y=3-X$).

Comment: Isn't every random variable independent of $X$, as it is constant?

Comment: $X(1) = X(2) =1$?

Comment: @AjayKumarNair Sorry, there was a typo in my answer. I have corrected it.

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that this example here works because $X$ and $Y$ here generate the whole sigma algebra. If yes, is there any way plausible way to extend this to any sigma-algebra?